# Security diagrams and UML

Tags: security, architecture, uml

I want to draw up a diagram that will show the security of the application.

What UML diagram is most typically used for this task?

Is there a non UML diagram that is typically used for this task instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDL Threat Modeling Tool 3.1.8 is an add-on to Visio
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2955

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit facetious, don't model the security of your application. Model the **in**security of your application instead. You can start with good models of your application's functionality (use cases), logical component structure and physical deployment, but use security methodologies instead of UML, which is focused on documenting what is there, rather than on what may be missing. [Attack tree analysis](http://www.schneier.com/paper-attacktrees-ddj-ft.html), at least in the hands of a security thinker (one who thinks like an attacker rather than a defender), tends to identify quite a lot of vulnerabilities and suggest possible remedies.

Be aware that the creator of a system seldom is the best person to do a security analysis: we tend to be over-protective of our babies. You should be at hand to answer questions, but not be out to prove yourself right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the diagram that describes the system from the desired prespective (deployment diagram, class diagram, collaboration diagram etc.) and used **stereotypes** to assign security properties to appropriate objects.